# Cakephp retrieve data in HABTM association

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 2 tables subscribers and distribution list and the relationship between them is HABTM. Now here particular users are associated to distribution list, i wish to add more users, but when adding new users to distribution list, i would like to show users who are not associated with that distribution lists. what condition should i write

Comment: NOT IN will only give me subscribers which are not belonging any of the distribution list

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->DistributionSubscriber->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('distribution_id <>' => 1), 'fields'=>array('subscriber_id'), 'recursive'=>-1));
```

I would try something like this.  You want to start with the join table in this case, and do your find() from there.  I haven't checked this syntax, but you should get the idea.

Comment: this would give me list of subscribers which are NOT there in the distribution list but rest of the entries in that join table